# Running a function in background with Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, background, parallel-processing

I want to run a function Get_List in the background and while it's running, the screen should show "Searching for Information" + dots to make it look like work is being completed.

```
function Get_List {
    #Some basic command to run in the background
}
```

.

```
function Other{
    #start the Get_List function in background

    while(Get-Job -State "Running")
    {
        #show "Searching for Information"
        #no need to code this part for me
    }
}
```

I have seen many people with similar questions, but mine (I think) is a bit different. No parameters are being passed, I just want to run something on the background which takes about 5-10 seconds and when it's done, that's it.

I am trying to be as simple as possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, what is your question, what have you tried, and what error did you get?

Comment: Why? If you really need feedback, use `write-progress` in `get_list`. Background jobs are a waste if you're just waiting anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternative approach is to use Write-Progress to show your fake or actual progress. Have a look at
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.powershell.aspx